# Is there any way to get a Terraform module to check if other modules output a particular object?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, openid-connect

I use OpenID Connect (OIDC) in my Kubernetes Terraform setup and want to automate the client/provider setup for each module that uses OIDC.

I thought of having each module (that uses OIDC) output a map with client_id, client_secret, requested_scopes and redirect_url. This map is appended to a list that the OIDC module can then process.

Is there any way to do this? Can I do it within the OIDC module, or should the map be concatenated in the root module and then passed to the OIDC module? Is there any way (or need) to declare this dependency for the OIDC module, so it doesn't process the list before all modules are finished?

I was thinking something like this, if it was a fictional python script:

```
for module in modules:
  if "oidc_config" in module.output.keys():
    oidc_module.process(module.output.oidc_config)
```

I haven't tried yet, I was wondering what the correct way to achieve this is.

Comment: No. There is no such construct in TF.